# $scope.$apply didn't work on jQuery plugin after API service call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using [third party jQuery tabs plugin](http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/) to navigate my web application. Every tab below has "next" button. When the next button is click, it will trigger the function `onNext`. From there, I can validate my fields before moving to the second tab. The validation works well, if I tried to validate all the fields. But when I validate through API calls and return the data. It doesn't work. I had been used `$scope.$apply()` and `setTimeOut`. Both didn't work.

**Controller without service (Working Example)**

```
jQuery('.js-wizard-classic-validation').bootstrapWizard({
       'tabClass': '',
       'previousSelector': '.wizard-prev',
       'nextSelector': '.wizard-next',
  'onTabShow': function(tab, nav, index) { }
  'onNext': function(tab, navigation, index) {
     if(index == 1){
       // This is when the 'next' button is click on the first tab
       var full_location_validated = false;
       // All the if else statements goes here to validate the fields
       $scope.$apply(); // Without this, next button will does nothing never update
       return full_location_validated;
     }
  }
```

**Controller with service (Doesn't Work)**

```
jQuery('.js-wizard-classic-validation').bootstrapWizard({
       'tabClass': '',
       'previousSelector': '.wizard-prev',
       'nextSelector': '.wizard-next',
  'onTabShow': function(tab, nav, index) { }
  'onNext': function(tab, navigation, index) {
     if(index == 1){
       // This is when the 'next' button is click on the first tab
       var full_location_validated = false;

       // Assume service return (success == true)
       myService.ValidateLocation(function(success){
            if(success == true)
               full_location_validated = true;
            else
               full_location_validated = false;
       });

       /* CASE 1 */
       // $scope.$apply();
       // return full_location_validated; // it returns false

       /* CASE 2 */
       setTimeout(function(){
         $scope.$apply();
         return full_location_validated; // it returns true
       },1500);
     }
  }
```

**Problem**

> When the next button is clicked, nothing happens because full_location_validated returns false instead of true with service.

Comment: can you make a plunkar?

Answer (score 0):

I see in your code following issues:

#### 1) Avoid to use `setTimeout`

If you write Angular application, don't use `setTimeout`, use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead. Angular doesn't know about `setTimeout` delay and you need to use `$scope.$apply();`.

This code snippet:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $scope.$apply();
     return full_location_validated; // it returns true
   },1500);
```

You can replace with:

```
$timeout(function (){
  return full_location_validated;
}, 1500);
```

---

#### 2)  `myService.ValidateLocation` its a Async call:

```
 myService.ValidateLocation(function(success){
        if(success == true)
           full_location_validated = true;
        else
           full_location_validated = false;
   });

// ...
 return full_location_validated;
```

You first return `full_location_validated` as `false` and only after some delay (in your case 1500 ms) you `full_location_validated` turned to be a `true`.

To make it work I would try to use [Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) or get rid of hard coded value 1500ms like:

```
 var releaseTimeout = false;

 myService.ValidateLocation(function(success){
        if(success == true)
           full_location_validated = true;
        else
           full_location_validated = false;
        releaseTimeout = true;   
   });


 var waitForValidate = function () {

   $timeout(function () {
       if(!releaseTimeout){
           return waitForValidate(); 
        }
        else{
         return full_location_validated; 
        }              
    }, 100);
 };

return waitForValidate();
```

<sup>**Didn't test it</sup>

---

#### 3) DOM manipulations and using 3d party

Its not a good practice to do  DOM manipulations and using 3d party like jQuery, in controllers. Create directive for that purpose.

Comment: Hello, I tried your second solution. It works well in Mac machine. But when I tried to run in Linux. it execute $timeout function once only.